# How to create a sheet slide from the right side as if it were a bottom sheet dialog?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I would like to create a slide sheet that fences from right to left, as if it were a navigator drawer but on the right side, I would like to know if there is an implementation as if it were a BottomSheetDialogFragment because in BottomSheet I do not have to modify the XML of the activities where I want to add it, because I have seen that in the NavigatorDrawer if it is modified.

Comment: do you mean a navigation drawer that shows in RTL mode?